# Confusion on when to use CDF and Poisson process

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution, poisson-process, cumulative-distribution-functions

---

I'm going through the MIT OCW probability course (6.041sc), but I'm having trouble on when to use CDF and the Poisson process. Here's the problem (Recitation 15, problem 1).

---

### **Problem Statement:**

Beginning at time $t=0$, we begin using bulbs, one at a time, to illuminate a room. Bulbs are replaced immediately upon failure. Each new bulb is selected **independently** by an **equally likely choice** between a a type-A bulb and a type-B bulb. The lifetime, $X$, of any particular bulb of a particular type is a random variable, **independent of everything else**, with the following PDF:
\begin{aligned}\text{for type-A bulbs: }f_X(x) &= \begin{cases}e^{-x}, x\geq0,\\0, \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}\\\text{for type-B bulbs: }f_X(x) &= \begin{cases}3e^{-3x}, x\geq0,\\0, \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}\end{aligned}

Find the **probability** that there are **no bulb failures** before time $t$.

---

### My Attempt:

I used the **total probability theorem** and then computed the **CDF**, $F_X(t)=P(X\leq t)$
:
\begin{aligned}P(\text{no bulb failure before time }t)&=P(A)P(X\leq t|A)+P(B)P(X\leq t|B)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t{e^{-x}}{dx}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t{3e^{-3x}}{dx}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-e^{-t}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-e^{-3t}\right)\end{aligned}

---

### Solution:

\begin{aligned}P(\text{no bulb failure before time }t)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-3t}\end{aligned}

I was able to reproduce this result using the **PMF** for the **number of arrivals** $N_t$ in a **Poisson process** with **rate** $\lambda$, over an **interval of length** $t$.
\begin{aligned}P_{N_t}(k)=e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}, \text{ }k=0,1,\dots\end{aligned}
In this context, we're looking at **no arrivals**, so $k=0$. And I figured that the **arrival rate** would be $\lambda=1,3$ for type-A(and type-B respectively) but I'm not sure why. Plugging in the appropriate numbers and using the **total probability theorem** we get the answer above.

---

### **My questions:**

1. Why did the CDF give me a different result? I'm sure that computing $P(X\leq t)$ was a valid approach, because that's the probability of the lifetime being at most $t$, but I must have some sort of conceptual misunderstanding on this.
2. How would I know that the arrival rate for type-A is $1$(and $3$ for type-B)? The only way I'd think of that is the fact that both type A and B are exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda=1,3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Note your result is
$$
\frac{1-e^{-t}}{2} + \frac{1-e^{-3t}}{2}
 = 1 - \frac{e^{-t}+e^{-3t}}{2}
$$
since when you pick cdf, $F_X(t) = \mathbb{P}[X < t]$ is the probability bulb fails before $t$ and you need probability of no failures, so $1-F_X(t)$.

(2) Your argument makes sense.